# Best Webservice for Android and Mysql

Tags: android, json, web-services

I'm developing android app, and need some webservices to communicate with my remote mysql database. I made same work and I created json webservice with php. But it seems complex to me. Because I want to use methods in webservice like .net webservice (asmx). Is there any solution for this problem. My server runs mysql and php. Is Json best solution for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php). It provides all the steps to send and receive data to and from MySql database using php. It helped me a lot when I developed the gps tracker app. Try it!

Answer (score 0):

If your application work with textual data, JSON is a good solution since android SDK provides a good support for it as well as PHP. And you can easily use PHP and MySQL together because of PHP’s strong integration with MySQL.